# Fetch data from Object type c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a WebAPI controller written in c# which look like this:

```
public void Post(Object obj)
{

}
```

Now, using `$resource` of angularjs I am posting a object like `{name: "xyz"}` to this controller.

So, obj seems like a object with property "name" and value "xyz" (quotes for clarity). How can I extract the value of the property name from the obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a DTO so you would have something like this.

```
public void Post(MyDTO dto){
  doStuff(dto.name)
}

public class MyDTO{
   public String name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I know , but I want to fetch data from Object obj.

Comment: Then I would use a dictionary, that should work for what you want, although I would say if you're sending up random objects you're probably doing something wrong.